# Cardinality: is it true that $|X^\mathcal{inj}| \leq 2^{|X|}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

**Definition.** Whenever $X$ is a set, write $X^\mathcal{inj}$ for the collection of all injections $f$ such that:

1. $f$ has codomain $X$
2. There exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $f$ has domain $\alpha$.

**Proposition.** Assume $\mathrm{ZFC}.$ Then $|X^\mathcal{inj}| \geq 2^{|X|}.$

*Proof.* Define a function $e : X^\mathcal{inj} \rightarrow 2^{X}$ by writing $e(f) = \mathrm{im}(f)$. Since every subset of $X$ is well-orderable, hence $e$ is a surjection. We conclude that $|X^\mathcal{inj}| \geq 2^{|X|}$.

> **Question.** Does the converse hold for infinite sets?
>
> In particular, assuming $\mathrm{ZFC}$, is it true that for all infinite sets $X$, we have $|X^\mathcal{inj}| \leq 2^{|X|}$?

Comment: It does certainly not hold for finite $X$ (with at least three elements). So I wouldn't bet on it to be true for infinite $X$.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ *any* ordinal? Some *fixed* ordinal? What is it? If $\alpha>|X|$ then $X^{inj}=\varnothing$ and $2^{|X|}\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, $\alpha$ is any ordinal. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's count stuff.

There are exactly $|X|^+$ many ordinals which can be injectively mapped into $X$. 
Omitting all the finite ordinals since their cardinality is negligible here.

Let $\alpha<|X|^+$, then there are $[X]^{|\alpha|}$ possible sets which can be the range of an injection from $\alpha\to X$, and there are $2^{|\alpha|}$ injections into each such set (fix one, then apply permutations on $\alpha$). Therefore there are $2^\alpha\cdot|[X]^{|\alpha|}|=|[X]^{|\alpha|}|=|X|^{|\alpha|}$ such injections for a fixed, infinite $\alpha$.

Therefore the result is $|X|^+\cdot|X|^{<|X|^+}=|X|^{<|X|^+}=|X|^{|X|}=2^{|X|}$.